# What sort of chemical would require a school to be evacuated?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I am doing research for a fictional story. I want to create an accident which would force students to be evacuated from a school. Is there a type of chemical spill that might take place in a chemistry class that would lead to all students being evacuated?

Comment: This is a very *broad* question because there are so many possible examples!

Comment: As seen in real life while in grad school, the following incidents required evacuation and visits from the fire department: bromine spill, peroxide formation in diethyl ether and accompanying spark of vacuum pump catching on fire, acrylamide incident, and the mother of all accidents involving sodium metal and ethanol dumped into a sink described [here](https://www.ehs.ucsb.edu/files/docs/ls/UT_fire.pdf). I was very thankful to be in a theoretical lab during my stint there.

Comment: Breaking a mercury barometer and not cleaning it up before the mercury goes into the cracks would do it. Or trying to clean up the mercury with a vacuum cleaner.

Comment: Mixing a couple of litres of hypochlorite and ammonia solutions .

Comment: The comments provide great examples, but they all were valid in the age of logic and reason. These days, it seems, a spill of dihydrogen monoxide in a chemical lab would cause a complete evacuation and a team in hazmat suits.

Comment: Asbestos found in the ceiling or walls

Comment: Just open a can of this food item: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surstr%C3%B6mming. It has actually been used at protests.

Comment: I recommend visiting Worldbuilding Stack Exchange for questions like this one.

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised no comments picked the easy choice; mercaptan( ethyl or methyl). The odorant that is added to natural gas. Several drops will stinkup a building as if there is a gas leak and evacuation will be ordered. I suppose if someone immediately confessed to the spill the evacuation might be cancelled. If it is done deliberately one would put it somewhere in the ventilating system. No health risk other than falling down while evacuating.

Answer (score 0):

Given that an answer has been provided and if you continue to insist on committing a crime, a possibly less damaging path for clean up and otherwise  problematic (so that you could try arguing 'harmless prank' upon your arrest) is to ignite a magnesium ribbon inserted into a metal container filled with an ammonium salt. This creates a smoke screen.

My safest choice would be ammonium citrate or ascorbate. However. the smoke itself could still possibly trigger an asthmatic attack which is just one example of what could go very wrong.

Also, please note that anyone injured in an evacuation, precipitated by your actions, may seriously escalate the criminal charge(s), so do re-consider, especially if you cannot afford a good lawyer or do not have a strong affinity for prison life.